# Kivy self manager get screen - not working

Tags: python, kivy

recently I try to make that app with python and kivy. After tons of hours googling everything together i more or less have everything i want. Only one thing is missing:

I have several screens. At the beginning of the App I have a menu. After that i have lots of questions; all of them have the same text and buttons in the bottom of the screen. I managed to make that the following way:

```
<firstquestion>:
    name: "firstquestion"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1

                NeuLabelinBox:
                    text: "Here the Question"

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: 0.1

            UnteresMenue:
```

Please notice "UnteresMenue" which refer another Class in the kv language. I think I somehow mixed 2 Screens together in one. The kv code of "UnteresMenue"

```
<UnteresMenue>:
    name: "UnteresMenue"
    #id: UnteresMenue


    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        NeuButton: 
            text: root.labeltext
```

Now for the python part:

```
class UnteresMenue(Screen):
    labeltext = StringProperty("Answer")
```

That works fine. But now I want to change the text of the label  in this "UnteresMenue", when I press a certain button at the beginning of the app (Start Questions). The label in the "Untermenue" should change to a certain text. So to do this:

```
text: "Exam"
self.manager.get_screen('UnteresMenue').labeltext = text
```

For all other classes this method works fine. But not for that certain class "UnteresMenue". Is it because it is implemented in the question and therefor kv does not recognize its properties?

For any small hints I would be more than grateful!

Here an "Mini" Example:

In the Main Menu you get to the "Exam" Section (Press Here in the example). While entering this Section (Prüfungsmodus) the property of the questions should change. "Press Here" again to get to the questions.

Normally it says in the Top of the questions "This should change" And THIS  is supposed to change the label into "Zeit" while entering the Prüfungsmodus Screen  (Class  def on_enter, in the python file), but it doesn't...

Python File:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, TransitionBase
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, InstructionGroup, Line, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial
from kivy.uix.image import Image

from kivy.garden.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer as ND

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
import random 
import time

Window.clearcolor = (0.2,0.2, 0.2,1)
Window.size = (480, 800)


#---------------------------------             Hauptmenü           -------------------------------------------

class hauptmenue(Screen, Widget):
    pass

class Pruefungsmodus(Screen):


    labeltext2 = StringProperty("hi")


    def on_enter(self):
        text = "Zeit" 

        self.manager.get_screen('OberesMenue').labeltext = text  #DAS Klappt nicht

    def StartPruefung(self):


        sm.current = "ersteFrage"  


class UnteresMenue(Screen):

    background_color_Kappa = ListProperty([0.2,0.2,0.2, 1]) 


class OberesMenue(Screen):

    BildLabeltext = StringProperty("Bilder\Loesung_Bild_pressed.png")
    BildLabeltext2 = StringProperty("Bilder\Loesung_Bild.png")
    labeltext = StringProperty("This should change")



class ersteFrage(Screen):

    pass





class WindowManager(ScreenManager):

    pass




kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
sm = WindowManager()


sm.add_widget(hauptmenue(name="hauptmenue"))



sm.add_widget(Pruefungsmodus(name="Pruefungsmodus"))       

sm.add_widget(OberesMenue(name="OberesMenue"))    
sm.add_widget(UnteresMenue(name="UnteresMenue"))   
sm.add_widget(ersteFrage(name="ersteFrage"))  
sm.current = "hauptmenue"






class Vorbrereitung(App):
    pruefung = ObjectProperty(None)
    def build(self):

        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Vorbrereitung().run()
```

my.kv file :

```
#:include alleFragen.kv

<NeuLabel2@Label>:


    halign: "center" 
    color:1,1,1,1 # <-----------
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.2,0.2, 0.2,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size  


<NeuLabelinBox@Label>:


    font_size: "22sp"
    color:0,0,0,1 # <-----------
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.949019608,  0.949019608,  0.949019608, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size  

<NeuCheckBox@CheckBox>:

    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.949019608,  0.949019608,  0.949019608, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size  


<NeuButton@Button>:

    font_size: "22sp"

    background_normal: ''
    #background_normal: "background.png"
    background_color: 0.92549,0.92549,0.92549, 1
    color:0,0,0,1 # <-----------
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.2,0.2, 0.2,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size   


<NeuButtonKappa@Button>:

    font_size: "40sp"

    background_normal: ''

    background_color: 0.2,0.2,0.2, 1
    color:1,1,1,1 # <-----------
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.2,0.2, 0.2,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size              

#----------------------------------            Hauptmenue          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<hauptmenue>:
    name: "Hauptmenue"

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        #spacing: 20


        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            padding: 20
            size_hint_y: 0.2           


            NeuLabel2:
                size_hint_x: 0.6
                text: ""
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'


        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            padding: 30
            spacing: 20

            size_hint_y: 0.5
            BoxLayout:
                NeuButton:
                    text: ''

            BoxLayout:
                NeuButton:
                    text: 'PRESS HERE'
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "Pruefungsmodus"
            BoxLayout:
                NeuButton:
                    text: ""
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'middle'

            BoxLayout:
                NeuButton:
                    text: ""
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 10
            size_hint_y: 0.15

            NeuButton:
                text: ''

#----------------------------------            Pruefungsmodus          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<Pruefungsmodus>:
    name: "Pruefungsmodus"
    #background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    id: pruefungsmudos

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        #spacing: 20


        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            padding: 20
            size_hint_y: 0.2           
            Image:
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                source:"Bilder\Logo.png"   

            NeuLabel2:
                size_hint_x: 0.6
                text: 'Pr\u00FCfungs\nmodus'
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 12**4
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'

            Image:
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                source:"Bilder\Logo2.png"     


        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            padding: 30
            spacing: 10

            size_hint_y: 0.4
            NeuLabelinBox:
                id: text2
                text: root.labeltext2
                color: 0,0,0,1 # <-----------
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.949019608,  0.949019608,  0.949019608, 1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size 

        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            padding: 30

            size_hint_y: 0.2    

            BoxLayout:
                padding: 30
                spacing: 10
                NeuButton:
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                    text: "Press Here" 
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "ersteFrage"



                NeuButton:
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                    text: ""
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "hauptmenue"

#----------------------------------             Erste Frage           ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<ersteFrage>:
    name: "ersteFrage"


    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: 0.08

            OberesMenue:


        GridLayout:
            cols: 1

            size_hint_y: 0.1 

            NeuLabel2:
                font_size: "18sp"
                text: "Wie lautet......."        


        GridLayout:
            cols: 1


            size_hint_y: 0.7

            padding: 20
            background_color: 0.92549,0.92549,0.92549, 1  
            rows: 2
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:'horizontal'
                NeuLabelinBox:
                    text: "h+u=ZU" 
                NeuCheckBox:

                NeuLabelinBox:
                    text: "h+u=ZU"                    
                NeuCheckBox:

            BoxLayout:
                orientation:'horizontal'

                NeuLabelinBox:

                    text: "h+u=ZU" 
                NeuCheckBox:

                NeuLabelinBox:
                    text: "h+u=ZU"

                NeuCheckBox:

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1


            size_hint_y: 0.1


            UnteresMenue:
```

and the outsourced Top and Button Menu:
alleFragen.kv

```
<OberesMenue>:
    id: OberesMenueee

    name: "OberesMenue"


    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        GridLayout:
            #size_hint_y: 0.05
            spacing: 20

            cols: 3
            NeuButton:
                text: ""
                size_hint_x: 0.16

                background_color: 1,1,1, 1
                background_down:  root.BildLabeltext
                background_normal:  root.BildLabeltext2
                color:1,1,1,1 # <-----------
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.2,0.2, 0.2,1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size  

            NeuLabel2:

                size_hint_x: 0.8 

                text: root.labeltext

            NeuButtonKappa: 
                size_hint_x: 0.1 
                text: "MENU"
                background_down: "Bilder\HintergurndFarbe_app.png"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "hauptmenue"


<UnteresMenue>:
    name: "UnteresMenue"
    id: UnteresMenuee


    GridLayout:
        cols: 5
        spacing: 20
        padding: 20
        NeuButton: 
            text: "<=="

        NeuButton: 
            text: "<"

        NeuButtonKappa: 
            text: 'k'
            #background_color: root.background_color_Kappa
            background_down:  "Bilder\HintergurndFarbe_app.png"

        NeuButton: 
            text: ">"

        NeuButton: 
            text: "==>"
```

Comment: You say "not working". Do you get ant error messages?

Comment: not at all. It just ignores the command. Everything is working fine without any errors

Comment: Then you will probably need to post a [mcve] in order to get any help.

Comment: I did update my Question with an example. I hope this is ok :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different instances of the `OberesMenue` Screen.

There is one created in your python:

```
sm.add_widget(OberesMenue(name="OberesMenue"))
```

And you have another created in your `kv`:

```
<ersteFrage>:
    name: "ersteFrage"


    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: 0.08

            OberesMenue:
```

In order to acces the second instance of `OberesMenue`, you can add an `id`:

```
<ersteFrage>:
    name: "ersteFrage"


    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: 0.08

            OberesMenue:
                id: in_ersteFrage
```

Then in your `on_enter()` method of `Pruefungsmodus`, you can change that instance by using:

```
def on_enter(self):
    text = "Zeit"

    self.manager.get_screen('ersteFrage').ids.in_ersteFrage.labeltext = text  #DAS Klappt nicht
```

Note that this changes the `Label` in the second instance of `OberesMenue`, but has no effect on the first. Your original code was changing the first instance, but not the second. And you can't put the same instance in both places at the same time, since a `Widget` can have only one parent at a time.

So, if those instances are intended to be identical, then you need to change the `Label` in both.

If you really want to share the same instance, you can keep your own record of where it is and use `remove_widget()` and `add_widget()` to move it from one parent to another.